# Trying to programmatically redirect

Tags: redirection

I’m trying to redirect users in Drupal 8 as I was used to do in Drupal 7 with a simple `drupal_goto()`.

This is my code.

```
$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url($url_redirect));
$response->send();
```

Executing it, I get the following error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route `http://mydomain.es/participar?utm_source=RTB&utm_campaign=&utm_medium=banner&utm_term=1`
>   does not exist.

The alias /participar exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't send the response, return it.

Answer (score 5):

See [drupal_goto() has been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537).

> #### Drupal 8 (procedural)
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
>
> function my_menu_callback_foo() {
>   //....
>   return new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('user.page'));
> }
> ```
>
> #### Drupal 8 (properly injected)
>
> ```
> use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
>
> class MyControllerClass extends ControllerBase {
>
>   public function foo() {
>     //...
>     return $this->redirect('user.page');
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> If the route name is not known use `RedirectResponse` with a URL. When redirecting to an external location, use `TrustedRedirectResponse`.
>
> ```
> use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
>
> class MyControllerClass extends ControllerBase {
>
>   public function foo() {
>     //...
>     return new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://example.com/some/path'); // for eg. Url::fromUserInput(\Drupal::destination()->get())->setAbsolute()->toString();
>   }
> }
> ```